# Start activity when the activity is open inside broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

I am  trying to open an activity inside broadcast receiver.
I can do that through intent, but it will open that activity only one time until i have close that activity.
How can i reopen activity when that is started from broadcast receiver?

Comment: My codes works as well when i am in my app and each time i have calling the new activity , then new activity will open. but my problem is when i am quieting from my app and trying to reopen the activity. only one time will open untill i have closed the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `intent.flag_activity_clear_top` for starting new activity or `intent.flag_activity_reorder_to_front` if activity is already running and bringing that activity to foreground.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks there. but intent.flag_activity_clear_top will replace with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ? or both will used?

Comment: If you want the new task then both can be combined but single clear_top flag will also work